# Completely prevent interaction with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `UICollectionView` that I want to show, but I may place a `UIView` overtop of it with a slightly translucent background. When that occurs I need to prevent the user from interacting with the collection view - they should only be able to interact with the view that appears overtop of it. To do that, I've made the view fill the collection view's bounds and that works well. However I noticed when users of VoiceOver use the app, if they tap on the view it will focus it but then if they swipe right to go to the next element it will focus the first cell in the collection view and allow interacting with it. How can I completely prevent interacting with the collection view for all users?

I've tried setting `scrollingEnabled` to `false` and also `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` for the `collectionView` but that didn't do the trick. The label I have within each cell is still accessible, therefore the entire collection view is accessible.

Comment: Are you sure that userInteractionEnabled didn't work? That's how it works for me - maybe you think you're setting it to false, but really aren't...

Comment: @Colin indeed setting `userInteractionEnabled = false` on the `collectionView` still allows VoiceOver to focus them, on both iPad and iPhone running iOS 8.1+. I confirmed it does get set to `false` and it didn't ever get set back to `true` during my testing.

Comment: @Colin It seems to focus the subviews of each `UICollectionViewCell`. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: Oops, my fault, I didn't fully realize what you were saying w/r VoiceOver. I don't know how that works. Sorry.

Comment: FWIW, the behavior with `userInteractionEnabled=false` makes sense when you think about what 'interaction' means; a user moving focus with VoiceOver is more analogous to a sighted user _reading_ UI, which is passive activity; if UI is visible to a sighted user, a VoiceOver user should also be able to discover/read it. Preventing interaction should only prevent them from _clicking_ or activating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`accessibilityElementsHidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityElementsHidden) is the property you want; should be able to set this to YES on the UICollectionView to hide that subtree. From docs:

> You might use this property to hide views that are covered by the arrival of a new view. In this case, the hidden views might remain visible onscreen, but they are not the focus of the user’s actions.

...which sounds like a good match for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If users really should be only able to interact with the view that is on top of it and no other view (including the collection view), consider setting `accessibilityViewIsModal` on the view that is on top.

To nicely see what `accessibilityViewIsModal` does in practice, consider seeing the excellent interactive Figure 1 at [Adding accessible behavior](http://ronnqvi.st/adding-accessible-behavior/#implementing-accessible-modal-views) by David Rönnqvist, in section "Implementing accessible modal views".

Comment: This almost works, but this view isn't really modal. You should still be able to interact with the elements around it, just not the collection view. This undesirably disables the ability to swipe left and right to navigate the other on-screen elements.